# Escape some characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have an ajax call in my legacy application:

```
i2b2.CRC.ajax.getQueryResultInstanceList_fromQueryResultInstanceId(
    "CRC:QueryStatus", {qr_key_value: rec.QRS_ID}, scopedCallbackQRSI
);
```

I want to add this Ajax request in `setTimeout` method. To escape `"` I added `\`. I came up with following line:

```
setTimeout("i2b2.CRC.ajax.getQueryResultInstanceList_fromQueryResultInstanceId(\"CRC:QueryStatus\", {qr_key_value: rec.QRS_ID}, scopedCallbackQRSI)",50000);
```

Now I am not getting any error on console but Ajax call is also not working either.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rec` and/or `scopedCallbackQRSI` variables are probably defined in a local scope (thus not accessible from the global scope). When `setTimeout` is called with a stringified function as a first argument, the function is executed within the scope of `window`.

To maintain the scope (and be able to use the local variables), wrap your code in a function, and pass it as a first argument to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    i2b2.CRC.ajax.getQueryResultInstanceList_fromQueryResultInstanceId("CRC:QueryStatus", {qr_key_value: rec.QRS_ID}, scopedCallbackQRSI);
}, 50000);
```

Comment: Ya they are define in local scope. Russ solution looks bit easy I guess.

Comment: Russ' "solution" doesn't work, because it's fundamentally not different from your current code.

Comment: I tried your solution no error but seems like Ajax request is not triggered.

Comment: @Ajinkya This solution should solve your main problem, if the request is not triggered, it's another problem.